# Can't use all features of remote web inspector of BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, web-inspector

Some features features of remote web inspector of BlackBerry 10 are not available. For example, if I press 'Elements', 'Network' or 'Timeline' button, nothing happens. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to disable all Chrome extensions and it worked.